# Pass a private key as a parameter when signing a file with X509 certificate

Tags: c#, x509

I'm new to c# programming, so please be patient.
I have to sign an xml file with CADES and I have a code found on the net that works great, but I can't pass the key to prevent the user from entering it. I searched for many hours before asking you, but I didn't find (or didn't understand) the solution. I don't want to use external libraries like Bouncy Castle.
This is the code for signing, all good.

```
 string cFileP7m = "testsigned.p7m";
 string cFileXml = "test.xml";

 try
 {
                X509Certificate2 oCert = GetCertificate();//return the x509 certificate from SmartCard
             
                ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1", "PKCS 7 Data"), File.ReadAllBytes(cFileXml));
                SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, content, false);
                CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner();
                signer.Certificate = oCert;
                signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
                signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1", "SHA256");                
                signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));

                try
                {
                    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
                    byte[] signature = signedCms.Encode();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(cFileP7m, signature);
                }
                catch (CryptographicException cex)
                { MessageBox.Show(cex.Message); }

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
 
Maybe I should use RSACryptoServiceProvider, but I don't know how to do it.
```

I found this code but I don't know how to use it for my purpose:

```
 var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)oCert.PrivateKey;
 CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(CspType, CspName, ContinerName, new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(), "123456");
```

EDIT:GetCertificate() it reads a specific certificate from a SmartCard:

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        X509Certificate2 oCert = null;
        string cSerial = "a1234c5";

        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 certif in my.Certificates)
        {
            string cLeggi = certif.SerialNumber.Trim();
            if (cLeggi == cSerial.ToUpper().Trim())
            {
                oCert = certif;
                break;
            }
        }

        return oCert;
    }
```

Comment: What does `GetCertificate()` do, please show.

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent the user from entering it"? Users tend not to enter private keys.  signedCms.ComputeSignature will use the private key associated with the certificate if it's already known; if it isn't, you need to either mate it up using CopyWithPrivateKey or use .NET Core/.NET 5+ where you can specify it in the CmsSigner ctor along with the certificate.  But a lot of the answer hinges on what you actually are trying to do and/or prevent from happening.

Comment: @bartonjs, Maybe I didn't explain myself well, I would like the signature to take place by entering the pincode of the certificate from the code and not through the Windows certificate store. Example (not real): oCert.pincode (key) = "123456";

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET Core 2.0+ or .NET 5+, then you might be able to do something like

```
using (X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificate())
using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    if (rsa is RSACng rsaCng)
    {
        string pin = ...;
        // The docs for the property say it needs to encode the trailing null character.
        byte[] propertyValue = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pin + "\0");
        rsaCng.Key.SetProperty(
            new CngProperty(
                "SmartCardPin",
                propertyValue,
                CngPropertyOptions.None));
    }

    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner();
    signer.Certificate = oCert;
    signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
    signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1", "SHA256");                
    signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));

    // Tell the signer to use a pre-configured key instance instead of fetching it
    // from the cert.
    signer.PrivateKey = rsa;

    try
    {
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
        ...
}
```

which is to say, set the [NCRYPT_PIN_PROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-property-identifiers#ncrypt_pin_property) property on the key instance.  The reason it requires using new .NET is that signer.PrivateKey is new (it's not present in .NET Framework 2.x/3.x/4.x).  As far as I know, there's no way to do accomplish your goal with the `SignedCms` class in .NET Framework.

The code you found for setting the PIN via a CspParameters would be appropriate if the key isn't an RSACng, but is an RSACryptoServiceProvider (meaning it requires using a legacy CAPI storage driver).  That really shouldn't happen, and if it does you'd need to restructure the code a bit since for CAPI you'd need to make a new RSACryptoServiceProvider instance instead of configuring the current one.

And as a final note, don't use the `cert.PrivateKey` property.  It's deprecated in newer versions of .NET in favor of the Get*PrivateKey methods (for a variety of reasons which are explained elsewhere).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, but I still use the 4.7 framework with Visual Studio 2019 and can't switch to .NET for many reasons. I will try to study RSACryptoServiceProvider.